# Java: A text file is double clicked. I want to load the file into a text editor but how do I get the file path of the clicked file?

Tags: java, swing, text, editor, filepath

Java: A text file is double clicked. I want to load the file into a text editor but how do I get the file path of the clicked file?

EX: There is a text file on the desktop with stuff written to it. I am trying to create my own text editor. I want to double click the text file and open the contents to my editor. How would I go about doing that?

I really just need to somehow grab the filepath. Once I get that I can extract the text myself.

-Thanks

Comment: IF your Java program has been correctly registered with the OS to launch when the file is double clicked, in most cases it will passed as part of the `main` method arguments.  This will also depend on the OS, as I think the Mac OS does things a little differently...

Comment: Sample code? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: when you say double clicked, are you talking about having the program running, and you double click it on the desktop? Or are you opening a file chooser?

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I double click the file my program opens. I have never access the main args. I will search for more info on that. Its Windows 7 BTW

Comment: @user2367327 You application must have a `main` method somewhere...

Comment: @tomArnold The program is opened when i double click the file. I would like the text that was in the file to be displayed in my program. (Just like if you double click on test.txt it opens the file in notepad and displays the text that was within the file.)

Comment: @user2367327 ok, so you want to create another application in java that you can use to open and edit a text file?  Ex. I right click test.txt and choose Open With MyJavaApp.  Which will launch the app and open the text file in the app?

Comment: I got it to work. I have created a simple text editor with swing..
I used
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);

            // Work with your 'file' object here
        }
    }

to get the file path. Then I used bufferedfile reader to extract the text.

Thank you all who helped!

Comment: I did not know that kind of stuff was what the Main args was for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path will be passed on your programs command-line, which is exposed to Java as the `String[]` parameter to `main()`.

Comment: This worked Thank you. i used

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);

            // Work with your 'file' object here
        }
    }